# Duvida Consulta SQL Dias Úteis

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Boa noite!

Galera, preciso saber de um seguinte resultado. Quero trazer os dias úteis agrupado por mês e ano de abril ate junho desse ano de 2017. Exemplo:

```
Ano    Mês    Dias Uteis
2017  Abril      19
2017  Maio       18
2017  Junho      17
```

OBS: Já existe uma função no nosso banco chamado dias_uteis que realiza o calculo normalmente dos dias uteis e feriados. Tentei fazer com a consulta abaixo, porém, sem sucesso.

```
 select (dbo.dias_uteis('01-04-2017','30-06-2017')) diasuteis, 
 DATEPART(month, dbo.dias_uteis('01-04-2017','30-06-2017') ) Mês,
 DATEPART(YEAR, dbo.dias_uteis('01-04-2017','30-06-2017')) Ano 
 group by DATEPART(YEAR, dbo.dias_uteis('01-04-2017','30-06-2017')), 
 DATEPART(MONTH, dbo.dias_uteis('01-04-2017','30-06-2017'))
```

Comment: O que a function dias_uteis retorna ? A quantidade de dias úteis do intervalo ? Seu problema e saber em um mês , crie uma versão desta função para isto , pode usar a que já existe o trabalho seria simples em tese.

Comment: Olá, a função é só para trazer os dias úteis em qualquer período. Nesse exemplo eu coloquei de abril até hoje.

Comment: @RenanBessa: Qual é a versão do SQL Server? // Como estão definidos os parâmetros para a função dias_uteis: date? char(10)? outro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sobre a questão de dias úteis sugiro a leitura do artigo “[Operações com dias úteis no SQL Server](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2020/12/02/operando-dias-uteis/)” que detalha formas de obter o cálculo, inclusive com o uso opcional de tabela de calendário.

Eis código que recebe como valores o período a emitir. A partir desses valores são gerados os meses e calculado o número de dias úteis para cada período mensal.

```
-- código #1 v3
--> informe a data inicial e final (formato dd/mm/aaaa)
declare @DataInicial date, @DataFinal date;
set @DataInicial= convert(date, '1/4/2017', 103);
set @DataFinal= convert(date, '30/6/2017', 103);

-- garante sequência nos parâmetros
IF @DataInicial > @DataFinal
  goto _FIM;

--
with cteData as (
SELECT @DataInicial as InícioMês,
      case when eomonth(@DataInicial) > @DataFinal
           then @DataFinal 
           else eomonth(@DataInicial) end as FinalMês
union all
SELECT dateadd(day, +1, FinalMês), 
       case when eomonth(dateadd(day, +1, FinalMês)) > @DataFinal
            then @DataFinal 
            else eomonth(dateadd(day, +1, FinalMês)) end
  from cteData
  where FinalMês < @DataFinal
)
SELECT year(InícioMês) as Ano, month(InícioMês) as Mês,
       dbo.dias_uteis (InícioMês, FinalMês) as [Dias úteis]
  from cteData;

_FIM:
go
```

O código utiliza a função [eomonth()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee634394(v=sql.110).aspx), disponível a partir da versão 2012 do SQL Server.

A versão 3 do código funciona também para casos em que o período de análise não envolve meses completos. Por exemplo, pode-se pesquisar de 5/3/2017 a 20/6/2017 ou mesmo por 10/2/2017 a 20/2/2017.

Comment: ôpa meu amigo, fico imenso agradecido. Funcionou bonitinho. Você é o cara! eu não conhecia essa função eomonth.

Comment: @RenanBessa: A partir da versão 2012 do SQL Server várias funções foram acrescentadas. Vale a pena consultar a documentação de funções.

Comment: Feito meu caro.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi direito essa função que você disse que tem, tentei fazer da maneira mais simples possível.

```
SELECT YEAR(dias_uteis) AS 'Ano',
MONTH(dias_uteis) AS 'Mes',
dias_uteis AS 'Dias Uteis'
FROM dbo
WHERE dias_uteis BETWEEN '01-04-2017' AND '30-06-2017'
GROUP BY MONTH(dias_uteis);
```

Comment: ôpa amigo, bem.. essa função é para trazer os dias uteis independente do período que eu escolher.

Comment: O comando que eu apresentei na resposta funcionou?

Comment: Não, como dbo.dias_uteis é uma função, ele precisa receber algum parâmetro. Exemplo: select (dbo.dias_uteis('01-04-2017','30-06-2017')). Essa consulta ele toma todos os dias uteis de abril até hoje, mas queria agrupar-los por mes.

Comment: Tente fazer da maneira que deixei na resposta, porém, com os parâmetros.

Comment: Fiz dessa forma como vc falou, porém, ele nao reconhece essa tabela dbo q vc mencionou. Dizendo que o nome do objeto dbo é inválido.

Comment: tá aqui a consulta já com os parâmetros.SELECT YEAR(dbo.dias_uteis('01-04-2017','30-06-2017')) AS 'Ano',
MONTH(dbo.dias_uteis('01-04-2017','30-06-2017')) AS 'Mes',
dbo.dias_uteis('01-04-2017','30-06-2017') AS 'Dias Uteis'
FROM dbo
WHERE dbo.dias_uteis('01-04-2017','30-06-2017') BETWEEN '01-04-2017' AND '30-06-2017'
GROUP BY MONTH(DBO.dias_uteis('01-04-2017','30-06-2017'));

Comment: Tire o `FROM dbo` e veja o que retorna. E segundo, qual o nome da tabela? Não é dbo?

Comment: Isso, ja tinha feito tirando o from, porém, ocorre a seguinte mensagem: Cada expressão GROUP BY deve conter pelo menos uma coluna que não seja referência externa.

Comment: SELECT YEAR(dbo.dias_uteis('01-04-2017','30-06-2017')) AS Ano,
MONTH(dbo.dias_uteis('01-04-2017','30-06-2017')) AS Mes,
dbo.dias_uteis('01-04-2017','30-06-2017') AS DiasUteis
WHERE dbo.dias_uteis('01-04-2017','30-06-2017') BETWEEN '01-04-2017' AND '30-06-2017'
GROUP BY MONTH(DBO.dias_uteis('01-04-2017','30-06-2017'));

Comment: Qual o nome da tabela?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select dbo.dias_uteis('01-04-2017','30-04-2017') abril,
       dbo.dias_uteis('01-05-2017','31-05-2017') maio,
       dbo.dias_uteis('01-06-2017','30-06-2017') junho
```

Creio que é isto