# SQL Query tempo médio NÃO levar em consideração Finais de semana e feriados

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Preciso calcular a média do tempo que leva desde a criação **(a.Data_Criacao)** ate a finalização **(s.Data_Status_Finalizado)** de um campo.

> **Não podendo contabilizar fins de semana e feriados.**

A query a seguir está funcionando, no entanto, leva em consideração todos os dias do periodo.

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(HH, a.Data_Criacao, s.Data_Status_Finalizado)) 
                                        FROM RTRC_Processo p
                                            Left join RTRC_Solucao s on (s.Id_Processo_RTRC = p.Id )
                                            Left Join RTRC_Abertura a on (a.Id_Processo_RTRC = p.Id) 
                                       WHERE 1=1 
                                        and s.Status ='F' 
                                        AND p.Data_Exclusao is null

                                        and YEAR(s.Data_Status_Finalizado) = 2019
                                        and MONTH(s.Data_Status_Finalizado)= 08
```

Comment: Qual o seu `SGBD`?

Comment: SqlServer. ....

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Função de dias úteis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/238258/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-dias-%c3%bateis)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Duvida Consulta SQL Dias Úteis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/217156/duvida-consulta-sql-dias-%c3%9ateis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie a função `fn_DiasUteis`

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].fn_DiasUteis
(
    @fromdate Datetime,
    @todate Datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
(

SELECT
    (DATEDIFF(dd, @fromdate, @todate) + 1)
   -(DATEDIFF(wk, @fromdate, @todate) * 2)
   -(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @fromdate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   -(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @fromdate) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   -(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @todate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   -(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @todate) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  As NoOfDiasUteis

)
```

Crie a tabela `feriados` e popule-a

```
CREATE TABLE feriados (
   dia datetime 
)



insert into feriados values ( '09/07/2019' )
--insert into feriados values ( '10/12/2019' )
--insert into feriados values ( '11/02/2019' )
insert into feriados values ( '11/15/2019' )
insert into feriados values ( '12/25/2019' )
```

E você poderá consultar dias uteis entre duas datas assim:

```
declare @fromdate date;
declare @todate date;
declare @diasuteis int;

set @fromdate  = '09/01/2019'
set @todate = '12/31/2019'


set @diasuteis = ( select * from dbo.fn_DiasUteis( @fromdate, @todate )) 
- (select COUNT(*) from feriados where dia >= @fromdate and dia <= @todate)

print @diasuteis
```

> 75

Temos 75 dias uteis até o final do ano.

**Observação**

Ao popular a tabela de feriados não inclua os dias que caem sábado ou domingo, porque serão considerados duplamente.

Comment: Um alerta: a função fn_DiasUteis necessita que o DATEFIRST esteja 7.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui vai uma expressão SQL, no SGBD PostgreSQL, que fornece os dias úteis de um período. 
Considerei que existe uma tabela com o registro dos feriados e outros dias que não devem ser considerados (emendas, pontos facultativos, etc):

```
SELECT dia FROM
    (SELECT ('2019-09-01'::date+s.a*'1 day'::interval) AS dia
       FROM generate_series(0, '2019-09-31'::date -
                          '2019-09-01'::date, 1) AS s(a)) foo
  WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM dia) BETWEEN 1 AND 5
EXCEPT
SELECT dia FROM tab_feriado;
```

Comment: Como usaria isso no meu contexto?

Comment: Talvez fazendo uma função, a ser utilizada no lugar da DATEDIFF, que retornasse a quantidade de dias do período.